# iPhone RSS Reader, get image from rss feed

Tags: iphone, xml, image, rss, feed

i've a problem.
I've an app that download rss feed from a website. It works all fine, but i want to set image in table view where the articles appear. How can i get image from RSS Feed? I need the code.
For title, description i've done it perfectly, but i'm not able to recover image.

P.S. : sorry for my english, i'm italian :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I presume you have the URL of the image. You can do this:

```
//Normal text setting code
//Normal text setting code

NSString *imageURLString = [rssFeed objectForKey:@img"];
NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:imageURLString];

NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];

cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
```

That is the quick and *filthy* method. It's running in your UI thread etc, so it's going to be a terrible user experience. You can fiddle with performance on your own terms, but I'd suggest one of the following:

1. Load all your data asynchronously and fill the data as it becomes available
2. Load all of your data in a secondary thread, but show a loading spinner

For both of the above, you would put your images into an NSArray and then call them by doing `cell.imageView.image = [myImageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

The best solution however (and most complicated) though is called 'lazy loading'.

If you want to do lazy loading (the way facebook and twitter do it) you should check this out: [LazyTableImages](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009394-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2).

Happy coding, Zane

Comment: No, i don't have the url of the image. I have to know what key i have to use for get image from a single article of the rss feed. However this code would serve to me.

Comment: What's the URL of the RSS feed? You can look at it as raw xml with a browser like google chrome and look at the tags.

Answer (score 0):

There is a plugin for it.
WP RSS Images Plugin
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-rss-images/

After downloading it and succesfully installing it you need to parse the enclosure tag.
It will be in enclosure element with the attribute of "url". If you need I can post the code also.

Comment: Your answer will improve if you post your code, that way others can benefit from your answer too.